# The standard error in Poisson model vs bootstrapped SE

Tags: glm, bootstrapping, poisson, coefficients, standard-error

I was trying to compare the SEs from two approaches:

1. the SE printed in the results section in the GLM poisson model, vs.
2. the SE of the coefficient I got from bootstrapping (basically I resampled the same number of observations with replacement and fit a new Poisson model and get the coefficient, then I compute the SD of the coefficients from 1000 bootstraps)

However the SEs from the two approaches are quite different. The SE from the 1) is much smaller. I thought they would be numerically similar.

Anyone has a explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to answer without a reproducible example. The usual suspicion would be that there is overdispersion in the response variable, leading to conventional standard errors that are too small. Alternatives include standard errors from: bootstrap, sandwich, quasi-Poisson, or fitting a negative binomial model instead.

See Section 3 of https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v027.i08 for a worked example in R as well as Chapter 7.4 in https://discdown.org/microeconometrics/. These use the `sandwich()` function from the package `sandwich` which also includes a function `vcovBS()` for bootstrap covariances.